# How many subsets of $\{1,2...,n\}$ there are such that if $2$ exists in the set then $1$ isn't

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many subsets of $\{1,2...,n\}$ there are such that if $2$ exists in the set then $1$ isn't?

I think the approach is a recursive formula:

Let $b_n$ be the sequence:

If $2$ is in the set then there are $n-1$ options so $b_{n-1}$

If $2$ isn't in the set then either $1$ is in the set, then there are $n-1$ options so $b_{n-1}$ or, $1$ isn't in the set as well so there are $n-2$ options so $b_{n-2}$.

So the formula is: $b_n=2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$ and that I already know how to solve.

Is this right? Is there another way?

Comment: Hint: what subsets of $\{ 1, 2, ..., n \}$ aren't in there?

Comment: @JHance the subsets $\{...,1,2,....\}$? So it's $2^n-2^{n-2}$?

Comment: Yes, it is $2^n-2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set of size $n$ has $2^n$ subsets.  If $2$ is in the set then $1$ is not in the set means.  $2$ is not in the set or $1$ is not in the set (using $A\rightarrow B$ means $\neg A\vee B$.)  To turn this into exclusive cases:

1) $2$ is not in the set or (exclusively)
2) $2$ is in the set, but $1$ is not in the set.

Since these two options are exclusive, we can count he number of sets that satisfy either property

1) If $2$ is not in the set, you're talking about subsets of $\{1,3,4,\cdots,n\}$.  Since this set has $n-1$ elements, there are $2^{n-1}$ such subsets.

2) If $2$ is in the set, but $1$ is not, you're talking about subsets of $\{3,\cdots,n\}$ union with $\{2\}$.  This results in $2^{n-2}$ sets that have $2$, but not $1$.

Therefore, in total, there are $3\cdot 2^{n-2}$ sets that satisfy the conditions.